# Is it ethical to raise a child to be the perfect person if they would have to be removed from their biological family? (see description)

Tags: ethics

Imagine that, with science, we could predict (with 100% accuracy) how successful a newborn would be in life under ideal and controlled conditions. Is it unethical to take that child away from their biological family and raise them in those ideal conditions if they would greatly benefit society in the future?

Do not consider the family's rights in this scenario.

Comment: I think that it would be ethical as long as the rights of the biological family are not considered. The child will be benefiting from every skill their predetermined childhood gives them. Additionally, they will be able to live a fulfilling life. Furthermore, the environment they would have been raised in normally could be an environment where their talents would be wasted. This could be saving children from a bad life for the advancement of society.

Comment: You might find Plato's *Republic* an interesting thought experiment!

Comment: Of course under your ideal assumptions such utility is ideal for the said child, but the overall consequent is very uncertain and perhaps dramatically different from our current society. Since it seems very probable most newborns if not all would qualify under your ideal assumptions then it would mean most families would loose their opportunity to raise their lovely newborn baby and perhaps to cause them to loose interest to even conceive babies... Is such a consequent optimal if you're consequentialist?

Comment: Somebody has been watching Jim Carey movies.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show

Comment: "Do not consider the family's rights" sounds pretty unethical from the get go... Also "ethical" alone does not mean.much in this context. You need to say what moral school of thoughts you want to consider.

Comment: Assuming the kids are taken away young enough that they have no life plan or goals of their own, are they going to be assigned a specific purpose or just given the best environment possible and left free to do what they want (including finding and returning with their own family)? There is a huge and ugly potential for the kids to be objectified in your scenario.

Comment: What does it mean "to be the perfect person"? I mean that sounds as if you've "figured out life" which we haven't like there could be a perfect person for a job, but to fit a person to a job would likely be pretty unethical as you treat them as a tool not a person.

Comment: Science can't measure value, but if you could measure value and if you could determine that what's best for the child is to raise him without his family, and if you consider only what's best for the child and not his family or anyone else, then your question seems to answer itself. The question is basically: "Is it best for the child to do what's best for the child?"